# Contract Address for Swap Router for Goerli ARB

Tags: blockchain, tokens, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv2

Does anyone know an address or sanple address for Swap Router in Goerli Arbitrum Testnet Network?

Like this sample in mumbai
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x8954afa98594b838bda56fe4c12a09d7739d179b

Answer (score 0):

This is the link for swapRouter for Goerli Arb Network
https://goerli.arbiscan.io/address/0x81cd91b6bd7d275a7aeebba15929ae0f0751d18c#code

Answer (score 0):

Here Goerli Arbitrum. Verified SwapRouter
https://goerli.arbiscan.io/address/0xBFB197dAB8ADC9560F32198CFA5454beBE2655A0